# How do I create a Sharepoint list via a feature receiver and an existing list template

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have a list template in a MOSS List Template Gallery and I need to create a list using this template from a feature receiver.  This sounds really easy but I cannot find a way of doing this.

SPWeb has a GetCatalog method that returns an SPList with 1 item - my template - but it is an SPListItem and I need an SPListTemplate.  How can I 'convert' the item to the correct type?

Thanks

Comment: Oh and I tried using GetCustomListTemplates but this returns an empty collection :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GetCustomListTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.getcustomlisttemplates.aspx) method of the [SPSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.getcustomlisttemplates.aspx) object to get the [SPListTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplate.aspx) object representing your custom template. Then use the [SPListCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.add.aspx) method to create a new list from this template. In code this would look something like this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server/sites/site"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
  SPListTemplateCollection templates = site.GetCustomListTemplates(web);
  SPListTemplate template = templates["MyTemplates"];
  Guid listId = web.Lists.Add("Title", "Description", template);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, GetCustomListTemplates returns an empty list

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the internalname...something like this:

```
foreach (SPListTemplate template in web.ListTemplates)
 {
    if (template.InternalName.Equals("MyTemplateName")
     {
        return template;
     }
 }
```

Comment: web.ListTemplates does not contain our custom template.  Fracked if I know why...

Answer (score 0):

So, we gave up and instead have used a feature receiver to create the list totally from code.  ListDefs are a complete PITA - C# is a much more logical way to create lists, plus you get the added benefit of being able to code upgrades to lists.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Read my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635129/sharepoint-2010-sandbox-solution-uploaded-stp-files-to-catalogs-lt-using-featu/9331694#9331694).  With that you should get a result from GetCustomListTemplates instead of just an empty list.